# TcpClient resource disposal

Tags: c#, stream, dispose, tcpclient

Say I have a `Stream` produced via `TcpClient.GetStream()`. If I `stream.Dispose()`, is it necessary to dispose of the `TcpClient` that created the `Stream`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the implementations of `TcpClient.GetStream` and `TcpClient.Dispose` in ILSpy, I agree that you should not have a resource leak if you call `Dispose()` on the stream but not on the client.

However, I am not convinced it is a good idea anyway.

I'd ask why you want to avoid calling `Dispose()` on the instance of `TcpClient`. The contract implied by the fact that `TcpClient` implements `IDisposable` is that `Dispose()` should be called when an instance is no longer required.

If you break this contract:

- Is it going to be confusing to future maintainers of your code?
- What if the implementation of `TcpClient` changes in future versions?

Comment: This is as a result of getting myself into a dependency injection tangle. There's almost certainly a better way of confronting this resource cleanup issue, and reading your answer reminds me that relying on an implementation detail is unsound.

Answer (score 0):

OK. I got out Reflector to check this myself. If you call `GetStream` on `TcpClient` it initializes a member m_DataStream to a non-null value.

The body of the dispose method of TcpClient looks something like this:

```
        IDisposable dataStream = this.m_DataStream;
        if (dataStream != null)
        {
            dataStream.Dispose();
        }
        else
        {
            //some other disposal strategy
        }
```

Therefore, if I dispose the stream myself, I'm performing the same disposal as performed by TcpClient.

So as far as I can tell, if I dispose the stream it's unneccessary to dispose the TcpClient.

Does anyone disagree?

Comment: (in answer to a removed comment) if the stream exists then that's the only disposal work that TcpClient performs. Therefore, if I dispose of the stream, the TcpClient doesn't have to. So I don't need to dispose the TcpClient as it will do nothing that isn't done by manually disposing the stream.